# Can't increase Java heap in Debian

Tags: debian, tomcat, memory, java, outofmemoryerror

I'm setting up an environment to run some web apps developed in Grails, and deployed in Tomcat.
I made the default configuration and the first web app deployed just fine, but after logging in, the page no longer loads. When I check the logs, I'm getting an out of space error. I was reading a lot of posts and comments in blogs about how to increase the Java memory, which I did, but now, there's another error (after doing a setenv.sh file):

[image]

And my setenv.sh file looks like this:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms512m -Xmx512m"
```

When I execute the `java -version` command, I'm getting this:

```
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

And the memory available in the server:

[image]

Comment: If this is Debian, what about using `/etc/default/tomcat{7|8}`, which is the correct place to configure stuff like this.

Comment: Hi there! It's Debian server 8 I believe

Comment: @gf_ definitely trying that later. I'll let u know about how it went.